# How to spread the load in JMeter to run for certain period of time?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

**- Test Plan**

User Defined Variables

HTTP Request Defaults

- - Thread Group 1 ( set to execute 100 Loop Count)
- - - Transaction Controller 1
- - - - - HTTP Request 1
- - Thread Group 2 ( set to execute 600 Loop Count)
- - - Transaction Controller 2
- - - - - HTTP Request 3
- - Thread Group 3 ( set to execute 1200 Loop Count)
- - - Transaction Controller 3
- - - - - HTTP Request 3

When I trigger the executions, all the executions finish quickly. But I want the load to be for 60 minutes. That HTTP requests 1, 2 and 3 to be run at such intervals that they all run for 60 minutes spread across in such a way. Is there any way to do this in JMeter?

Answer (score 0):

By default JMeter executes Samplers as fast as it can (as soon as the previous response is get). If you want to limit JMeter's execution speed - take a look at [JMeter Timers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-timer) in general an at the following guys in particular:

1. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) which allows to set the desired number of requests per minute. Example configurations:

   - 100 "loops" per hour = 1.6 requests per minute
   - 600 "loops" per hour = 10 requests per minute
   - 1200 "loops" per hour = 20 requests per minute
2. [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer) which allows to set the desired number of requests per period of time

   Default configuration is suitable for your use case with 100 requests per hour, just set 600 and 1200 instead of 100 for other Thread Groups

   [image]